# Ensuring a thread is running across a Tomcat cluster

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, java-threads

My application is an auction application written in Java and running on Tomcat. Timing is important on the server. Currently, it only gets deployed as a single server application. However, I now need to provide some horizontal scaling and run it on three servers behind a load balancer. The issue I'm having is how to correctly implement the AuctionRunnerThread across these servers.  The AuctionRunnerThread basically does this.

```
public void run()
{
    while (true)
    {
        checkTheSchedule();
        // this could be "end the round", "calculate results", or "nothing"
        runTheCorrectAction();  
        sleep(100);  // 100ms
    }
}
```

This works perfectly on one server as the 100ms sleep ensures that the timing of the auction never gets off and that rounds end nearly at the exact moment they're supposed to, and results are calculated once and when they're supposed to.

The problem arises as I move to this multi-server approach. I want to ensure the thread is always running, even if one of the servers goes down.  I also seemingly cannot have the thread running at all times on every server, because calling `calculateResults()` twice could lead to corrupting the database with bad data.  Or `openAuction()` twice - one call would lead to an error since you can only open an auction once.  Some "ideal" solution would be to start this thread on one of the servers when all the servers are started, and the other apps become aware, somehow, when that thread dies (because of EC2 failure or thread crashing) and one of the other Tomcat servers starts it up locally.  Basically the cluster would ensure the thread is always running on *one and only one* accessible machine.

Are there any common solutions to this, or third party libraries?

Comment: You could solve this with a scheduler library like Quartz, by not having a continuous loop, but scheduling only the actions at the frequency you need (though every 100ms might be a bit too often for something like Quartz). Or having the thread running at all servers, but using some form of inter-process communication to obtain a lock. Only the server with the lock performs the processing, etc.. There are probably better solutions possible, though.

Comment: I would suggest rethinking your approach, i.e. how about turning that thread into a separate application (with embedded web server or deployed to a separate Tomcat) and deploy it in a container? Thus when the the container crashes it can automatically be restarted. No need to have those threads in multiple servers and run complex synchronization if they cannot run in parallel anyway.